# How to use afterSuite method of Gradle Test class in Java?

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-plugin

I am writing a gradle plugin in Java .   I found groovy code online to summarize test results which I would like to convert in Java plugin.

My attempt to use afterSuite(Closure closure) in Java gives me an error. 
No signature of method: org.test.sample.GreetingPlugin$1.doCall() is applicable for argument types: () values: []

My java code

```
Test testTask = (Test) project.getTasksByName("test", false).iterator().next();

testTask.afterSuite(new Closure<>(null){
            @Override
            public Object call() {
                System.out.println("Done !");
                return true;

            }
        });
```

I have kept the call() method to minimum to try out the syntax.Compilation is fine but fails at runtime. Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Documentation at https://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-2.5.8/html/gapi/groovy/lang/Closure.html?is-external=true confused me. Instead of using overriding call() method I used doCall() method and it worked.

Following code will format gradle test results into something like this.

---

### RESULT: SUCCESS 6 TESTS, 6 SUCCESSES, 0 FAILURES, 0 SKIPPED

```
Test testTask = (Test) project.getTasksByName("test", false).iterator().next();
testTask.afterSuite(new Closure<Void>(testTask) {
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            public void doCall(TestDescriptor desc,TestResult result) {
                if(desc.getParent()==null) {
                    String output = "RESULT: "+ result.getResultType()+" "+result.getTestCount()+" TESTS, "+result.getSuccessfulTestCount()+" SUCCESSES, "+result.getFailedTestCount()+" FAILURES, "+result.getSkippedTestCount()+" SKIPPED";
                    String lines = Stream.generate(()->"-").limit(output.length()).collect(Collectors.joining());
                    System.out.println("\u001B[33m"+"\n" + lines + "\n" + output + "\n" + lines);
                }           
            }
        });
```